# Django URL in template with slug

Tags: django

I have a template (home.html) where I want to list all the items in my model, and when I click on them, it will take the user to the details page of the item.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your loop you call each object `item`. But in the URL tag you refer to `instance`, which does not exist. You should use `item` there too.

```
{% url 'show_menuitem' menuitem_slug=item.slug %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error says keyword argument not found because you defined keyword argument named `menuitem_slug` in the `show_menuitem` url but you are passing `slug` as keyword argument which is not the django url patterns is looking for.

Change this line ,

```
 <h2><a href="{% url 'show_menuitem' slug=instance.slug %}">{{ item }}</a></h2>
```

to

```
 <h2><a href="{% url 'show_menuitem' menuitem_slug=item.slug %}">{{ item }}</a></h2>
```

Also make sure you change get_absolute_url method to ,

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('show_menuitem', kwargs={'menuitem_slug': self.slug})
```

Comment: then are you sure you dont have any of the Null slug in your database ?

Comment: and change instance.slug to item.slug in your for loop